# Why ComboBox doesn't throw an Exception when setting DataSource?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, combobox, datasource

First my code. I have a class:

```
class Person {
    public int Id { set; get; }
    public string Name { set; get; }
    public Person(int i, string n) {Id = i; Name = n;}
}
```

and a ComboBox object:

```
this.comboBox_Persons = new System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox();
```

and somewhere in my code:

```
List<Person> persons = new List<Person>() {
    new Person(5, "John"),
    new Person(8, "Mike")
};
comboBox_Persons.Items.Clear();
comboBox_Persons.DisplayMember = "Name";
comboBox_Persons.ValueMember = "Id";
comboBox_Persons.DataSource = persons;
```

and a static member and an event handler:

```
public static string test = "";

void comboBox_PersonsSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    test = test + "1";
    string id = (string) comboBox_Persons.SelectedValue;
}
```

The last line is wrong (it comes from an earlier version of my code) and it should be:

```
int id = (int) comboBox_Persons.SelectedValue;
```

and it took me some time to realize that my problem is in this line.

But my question is about the wrong version of the line and exactly about the code above.

Why no exception is thrown when comboBox_Persons.DataSource is beeing filled?

When my form is ready comboBox_Persons contains two items and it should display "John" and "Mike" but it does not. The combobox displays the type name (with namespace) of the class Person twice. Moreover, the value of the static field 'test' is "11" which means that the event handler has been invoked. But the next line (with casting to string) should throw an exception, but it does not. Why? And next, when I click on the combobox and change the selected value then the event handler is called and an exception is thrown (telling that it can't cast to string).

So, why combobox does not throw any exception when setting DataSource?

And why combobox displays type names instead of defined property 'Name'?

I wonder why this control behaves this way and I didn't find any answer in .NET documentation and on the Internet.

When I change the wrong line to the correct version everything is OK.

Comment: Do you have a `try/catch` block around the code in question?  You do not show one in your example.  Add it and see if the exception is raised.  Winforms can swallow exceptions depending on intricacies of the load process.

Comment: Interesting! I tried debugging the same code you posted, and it is throwing an exception in SelectedIndexChanged, however its not breaking the application. Looks like the exception gets caught somewhere??!!

Comment: Does it crash when running the program directly? I.e. outside of the debugger.  There is a certain class of exception that will occur when running the program but not while debugging.  You can always set exceptions to always cause a break (even caught ones) and this will at least let you see the exception.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey : No, I don't have the code in a try/catch block. But when I add a try/catch block, the code runs properly, so without the block an exception is thrown and swallowed somewhere.

Comment: @j.i.h. : No, it behaves the same running both directly and in the debugger.

Answer (score 3):

I was searching on google for the combobox source code to see how it is implemented and why exceptions are getting buried and I found this:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/69a0b831-7782-4bd9-b910-25c85f18bceb/visual-studio-doesnt-break-on-unhandled-exception-with-windows-64bit?forum=vsdebug

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8a7006a1-ad86-4aec-9604-d7ccf99ce00b/selectedindexchanged-handler-exception-treated-as-first-chance?forum=vsdebug

Interestingly enough, if you add a line to throw an exception in your SelectedIndexChanged event, the application doesn't crash!!

```
private void comboBox_persons_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        test = test + "1";
        string id = (string)comboBox_Persons.SelectedValue;
        throw new ApplicationException("Test");
    }
```

Apparently, this is an issue with 64 bit machines and there is a hotfix available for this issue. As stated in this post, exception prone code in Form_Load event doesn't break the application!! Similar is the case with combobox SelectedIndexChanged event.

I couldn't test the hotfix since I do not have Win 7 SP1 installed on my machine. However, from the comments in the blog, the hotfix doesn't actually fix all the issues with exceptions being buried in 64 bit machines.

I hope this information is helpful!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The links you have given let me know more. I'm using Win8 64bit and on this system throwing an exception from Form_Load works correctly. I have run my code (that using combobox) on Win7 SP1 32bit and an exception from SelectedIndexChanged event hasn't been thrown. I can't install the hotfix on it because it's not my computer. So I guess the problem is present on all Microsoft systems. And it's not a problem to solve a bug like casting to string or similar but it can be time-consuming to find it as it was in my case.

Comment: I know, silent exceptions are a developer's worst enemy! I am using Win7 64bit and I don't get exception in Form_Load either even after explicitly using 'throw'. I have seen different behavior when I change the target platform in my project. I hope they find a fix for it soon.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following and your combo box will work:

```
comboBox_Persons.DataSource = persons.ToArray();
```

This is what I would do:

```
Person p = (Person) comboBox_Persons.SelectedItem;
```

Now you have all properties of the person

*But the next line (with casting to string) should throw an exception, but it does not. Why?* - your value is integer. Casting integer to string should throw exception. Although, I believe, you don't have `int` there. "...it should display "John" and "Mike" but it does not. The combobox displays the type name (with namespace) of the class Person twice..." - Because you should do `persons.ToArray()` to get "John" and "Mike".

*So, why combobox does not throw any exception when setting DataSource?* - because it is only a setup and until some operation is performed, you can set anything as datasource.

Change this

```
public static string test = "";....test = test + "1";
```

To This

```
public static int test = 0; ..... test += 1;
```

Good luck

Comment: It actually throws an exception if you are casting the value to a different type!! You can convert an int to string, but "casting" will throw an exception. If you debug the above code, you will notice that 'invalid cast' exception is being thrown, but it doesn't abort the application anyway.

Comment: This is because his `SelectedValue` is not `int` the way his code goes. Once you do `comboBox_Persons.DataSource = persons.ToArray();` it should go away

Comment: In your answer, you quoted 'Why casting integer to string should throw exception?'. My comment is a response to that line. "Casting" to another type always throws an exception, where as conversion doesn't. In this case, exception will be thrown.

Comment: @T.S. : You have written "Because you should do persons.ToArray() to get 'John' and 'Mike'". I don't think it is necessary because when I put the casting in a try/catch block or change from casting to string to casting to int then the combobox displays proper names.

Comment: @Victor. I've done this exact method many times and never needed any try/catch. I don't remember why but one experiment showed setting DataSourse to Array of items worked better than List of type. Again, this experiments were done 3-4 years ago and I don't member most details but one thing I remember is to prefer Array to List of Type as Datasourse.